# Admob Ads service issue

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

[image]

My admob account is active and showing daily requests of around 20-30k but the impression is not showing. it's been around more then 1 month and still in same position. I have follow all the proper steps of integration in app. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know that this question is sufficiently related to technical topics to be a good fit for StackOverflow. Separately from the technical scope, this will also be difficult to diagnose without seeing what the flagged issues are in the policy center. I'm afraid that editing in policy center screenshots would still make this off-topic for StackOverflow but I hope you can provide that additional information in the right forum to get the help you need.